# Why instead of appearing the "required" attribute in the form element is appearing "1"?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form for a user create custom questions. The user needs to introduce the question and also the type of field (text, long text, checkbox, select menu, radio button) to create a custom question.

Then I have the Question model that has the getHtmlInput() function to output in the view the different types based on the custom question type.

And its working fine, the issue is that instead of appearing the "required" attribute appears "1" on the custom questions that in the pivot table "registration_type_questions" have the column "required" as "1".

Do you know why?

Question model:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'question', 'type', 'conference_id',
    ];

    public static $typeHasOptions = [
        'radio_btn',
        'select_menu',
        'checkbox'
    ];

    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }

    public function options() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\QuestionOption');
    }

    public function hasOptions() {
        return in_array($this->type, self::$typeHasOptions);
    }


    public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype = false) {

        $html = '';
        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "<select name='participant_question' class='form-control' " . ($required ?: " required") . ">" : '';

        if (empty($options)) {
            switch ($customtype) {


                case "text":

                $html .= " 


                    <input type='text' name='participant_question' class='form-control'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">";


                break;

                case "file":

                    $html .= " 


                    <input type='file' name='participant_question' class='form-control'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">";


                    break;

                case "long_text":
                    $html .= "

                <textarea name='participant_question' class='form-control' rows='3'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">"
                        . $name .
                        "</textarea>";

                    break;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                switch ($customtype) {
                    case "checkbox":
                        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                        break;
                    case "radio_btn":
                        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                        break;
                    case "select_menu":
                        $html .= "<option value='" . $option->value . "'>" . $option->value . "</option>";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "</select>" : '';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Use of the getHtmlInput() in the view:

```
@if ($allParticipants == 0)
    @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
            @if($customQuestion->hasOptions() && in_array($customQuestion->type, ['checkbox', 'radio_btn', 'select_menu']))
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    $customQuestion->options,
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}

            @else
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    [],
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}
            @endif
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}"
                   name="participant_question_id[]"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Generated HTML: (instead of required appear 1)

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Text</label>
    <input type="text" name="participant_question" class="form-control" 1="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Checkbox</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check1" class="form-check-input" 1="">    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check1</label></div> 
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check2" class="form-check-input" 1="">    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check2</label></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Radio</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" name="participant_question[]" value="rad1" class="form-check-input" 1="">    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">rad1</label></div> 
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" name="participant_question[]" value="rad2" class="form-check-input" 1="">    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">rad2</label></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">select</label>
    <select name="participant_question" class="form-control" required=""><option value="select1">select1</option><option value="select2">select2</option></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">textarea</label>
    <textarea name="participant_question" class="form-control" rows="3" 1=""></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">file</label>
    <input type="file" name="participant_question" class="form-control" 1="">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" href="#step2" class="btn btn-primary mb-4 float-right next-step" value="Confirm Registration">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this piece of code

```
($required ?: " required")
```

You're not setting anything as the statement is true (is required) so it put the default, you're telling that is require when is not, the correct syntax is

```
($required ? " required" : "")
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to, if the custom question is required add inside each question label this "<span class="text-primary">*</span>"?

Comment: I think in your question model, where's the switch statement you can add something like 
`case "long_text":
                    if($required)
                         $html .="<span class="text-primary">
                    $html .= "

                <textarea name='participant_question' class='form-control' rows='3'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">"
                        . $name .
                        "</textarea>";
                    if($required)
                         $html .="</span>"
                    break;`
Remember to mark this as correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks, do you know why appears "required=""" instead of only "required"?

Comment: Man, i think we're going too abroad from the original question and that is against this site rules. Be patient and read the code you'll learn much more from making mistakes. If you really need help just post another question and be an active SO member. :)